# Does the same operator norm imply the same spectral radius?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

> Let $(E, \| \cdot \|)$ be a real Banach space.
>
> Let $A$ and $B$ be two continuous linear operators mapping from $E$ to $E$.
>
> If they have the **same operator norm** (i.e., $\|A \| = \| B \|$),
> then could we conclude that **their spectral radius are also identical**, i.e.,
> $\rho (A) = \rho(B)$?

By Gelfand's formula, we know that $\rho (A) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \| A^n \|^{1/n}$, and  $\rho(A) < 1$ implies $\| A^n \| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

It seems that $\|A \| = \| B \|$ may imply $\rho (A) = \rho(B)$ , but I am not sure if it is true. Could someone help me out please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Wait, does Gelfand's formula apply to real Banach spaces? The proofs I know only apply to complex Banach spaces.

Comment: I think Gelfand's formula apply to real Banach spaces well, since it also apply to complex Banach spaces. Sorry, I'm quite new in this area and not sure about that:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.  Consider the operator $S:\ell^2\to\ell^2$ defined by 
$$(Px)(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
x(n)&:& n\text{ even}\\
0&:& n\text{ odd}
\end{array}\right.$$
$S_R:\ell^2\to\ell^2$ the left shift operator, and $I$ the identity operator on $\ell^2$.  Put $T=PS_R$.  Then $\|T\|=1=\|I\|$, but $T^2=0$, so $\rho(T)=0\neq1=\rho(I)$.